# Implementing a Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, scroll, css-position, implementation

I am very new at this, I can barely handle CSS and HTML. But I really liked this plugin so I gave it a try.

https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem

It's a sticky scroll plugin that removes and adds a position: fixed class to an item, depending on it's position in relation to its' container (if I understood it right). There's also a demo in that link.

Anyway the problem is that I can't get it working. I feel like I followed every instruction there. I put a 'stickem-container' class to my posts container, 
'stickem' to the list I wanted stickied, set up the CSS for the needed classes and put the jQuery sources inside the body tag. But nothing's working, it's as if I haven't changed anything at all. Anyone more familiar with jQuery that could take a look at the plugin's implementation method and tell me what I may have done wrong?

Here's a http://jsfiddle.net/epV47/1/. The list is supposed to move up and down when you scroll.

```
<div class="Post"> 
<div class="stickem-container">
     <ul class="nav stickem">
              <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">test</a></li>            
     </ul>

     <div class="Text">
          CONTENT HERE
     </div>



</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the plugin on the element. You added the plugin, but that doesn't inherently cause it to target an element and execute its self; you must.

```
$('.stickem-container').stickem();
```

[**Here's the Fullscreen jsFiddle (because of your margin-left:660px rule)**](http://jsfiddle.net/BGZeZ/embedded/result/)

[Here's the relevant code](http://jsfiddle.net/BGZeZ/)

Comment: By the way, I also have a infinite scroll plugin. Would you happen to know why the sticky plugin would suddenly stop working once the infinite scroll loads a new page? Only affects the posts on the new pages.

Comment: @user2534878 I'd have to see the page/code to see why it's not working.

Comment: http://oldtimesdaily.tumblr.com/ here's the page, the plugin works fine, till the infinite scroll plugin kicks in. It's okay if you don't find the issue though.

Comment: @user2534878 I just took a look at the page. I see the Menu appending to the top without issue as I scroll down the page and infinite scroll puts in more posts. No problems here in FireFox / Chrome / IE 9.

Comment: No no, not the top bar menu. The menu to the right of each individual post, the one with a thumbs up, windows icon and F share. It's moving when you scroll even on the new pages for you? Here's what I mean: http://postimg.org/image/5h7np4dtd/ as you can see the menu is on the top of the page, but the sticky plugin should have pulled it down. It doesn't have the "stickit" class either like the posts before the infinite scroll.

Comment: I think I know the problem, someone had a similar issue with another plugin conflicting and he said this: "I know I have to call it back after infinite scroll loads". Could that be the problem? How do I call a function back after each load?

Comment: @user2534878 destroy it, and re evoke it after.